# MySQL add values from all rows

Tags: php, mysql

How would I add up all the integers in the column, _view_count_, on my table, 'videos', then echo it to display on my page?

For example:

if row id 1 has `view_count == 328`

and

if row id 2 has `view_count == 271`

How would I make MySQL add those together and echo it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `$mysqli` object defined your code should look like:

```
$query = "SELECT Sum(view_count) as mySum FROM videos";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['mySum'];
```

Comment: As the `mysql_` functions are no longer recommended for use, please do not recommend the OP to use them - especially when they do not indicate their usage in their question.

Comment: That is correct mysql is now deprecated, lookup the equivalent functions in the mysqli libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL's [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) and your SQL query would look something similar to:

```
SELECT SUM(view_count) FROM videos;
```

To *query* and `echo` the value, if you're using `mysqli` methods in your PHP code, you can use:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT SUM(view_count) AS sum FROM videos;');
$row = $result->fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['sum'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SUM(view_count) FROM videos`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a COLUMN id, you can use **SUM** together with **IN**, like so:

```
SELECT SUM(view_count) FROM videos WHERE id in (1,2)
```